# When we compute the complexity of a given algorithm related to image processing does the N refers to the number of Pixels in the image?

Tags: algorithms, complexity

When we compute the complexity of an image processing algorithm, we get an $O(N)$.

does the $N$ refers to the number of pixels in the image **or** to the height/width of the image, I mean it is computed related to $O(nm)$ with $n\times m$ the size of the image ?

please, cite some references.

Comment: What has your literature search turned up?

Comment: I have not find any interesting references :(

Answer (score 2):

The only interesting quantity of a picture -- from a complexity perspective -- is the number of pixels, not its size.

Whether any given paper follows this observation is of course a different matter, but if nothing different is specified, I would assume that $N$ is the number of pixels indeed.